# Securely erase dead guys MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro

I was given this 2017 MacBook Air as part of an estate.
I want to erase it and reinstall Sierra OS that came with it, which I have on a USB.

I have followed several sets of online instructions, including the Official text “Mac OS Support Essentials 10.12”

The options in The Disk Utility that I purportedly need are grayed out.  I have installed the OS multiple times, which appears to have just recovered the existing OS and user setup. I have read online references to booting from another account to do this, and I now have a thunderbolt cable to go to a late 2006 imac 27 also running Sierra.

I have also read that there is a way to reset to NVRAM to disable the Find My Mac feature.

I thought Apple was superior to PC, but format C sure is simple...

Can anyone help me with getting the disk arased, New copy of OS in a clean install, and no more tracking of the laptop once it goes to the new owner?

Comment: Some people might find the security of a thief not easily being able to overwrite their entire disk as simply as ‘format c:’ a feature that does in fact make “Apple superior to PC.”

Comment: If you are looking for help it is probably not a great idea to throw shade in the direction of the people who you are asking for help from.

Comment: This might be hard to answer unless an edit explains what “tracking” is observed as well as a link to the procedure you’re following. There are thousands of online instructions and many are going to be wrong. If you could edit this to be more specific you’ll get better answers.

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to respond.  Good points , all.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say but I assume you are booting into Internet Recovery mode which allows you do do a lot more than just recover your Mac via the internet? If not that would be mistake number 1. If you are please proceed.

Boot into Internet Recovery and go into disk utility. Select the Mac HD (or whatever the primary/largest partition is and format it. You need to do nothing else, just format it.

Once you are done quit out of disk utility and go into the part that lets you reinstall the operating system. You may proceed with installing this way or if you have a bootable installer with another version of macOS on it you can reboot, holding down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key and selecting the installer USB key to boot from.

Either way, follow the prompts and reinstall macOS.

Once that is done and you have logged in. Use the App Store to update the installed OS (or upgrade to a newer version, your choice). Install your apps of choice and you may proceed to use the Mac.

Note that formatting the HD does not *securely wipe* the drive of previous data. But the process of installing macOS, your apps and documents will overwrite the drive, with your data. Once that is done the chance of recovering any of the previous owner's data is slim to none. And *completely* nil if you don't attempt to recover any of it.

Comment: This still doesn't disable Find my Mac. The original owners iCloud account will still be associated with the machine. The OP needs to contact Apple Support to disassociate it. Additionally, the OP needs to reinstall the original OS first installed on the machine - with his/her own Apple ID. If the OP uses the bootable installer option, he/she won't subsequently be able to upgrade or update the OS since it isn't tied to any Apple ID.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't considered that, thx!

Answer (score 0):

I am a huge fan of DBan (https://www.pendrivelinux.com/install-dban-to-a-usb-flash-drive-using-windows/), could work if you can remove the harddrive and plug it in to an other PC temporarily.

After erasing the disk, you can reinsert the HDD and perform a normal, clean install on it.